# rotate: a b c ddeg; only supported by Firefox but adding browser prefixes seems to break it for Firefox too

Tags: css, css-animations

```css
.object-wraps{width: 100px; height: 100px; background: gray;}

.object-wraps:hover {
    -webkit-animation-name: object-skew; 
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    
    -moz-animation-name: object-skew; 
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-duration: 2s;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    
    -o-animation-name: object-skew; 
    -o-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -o-animation-duration: 2s;
    -o-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    
    animation-name: object-skew; 
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes object-skew {
0%   {rotate: 0 0 0 0deg;}
45%  {rotate: 1 1 0 15deg; }
50%  {rotate: 1 1 0 15deg;}
}

@-moz-keyframes object-skew {
0%   {rotate: 0 0 0 0deg;}
45%  {rotate: 1 1 0 15deg; }
50%  {rotate: 1 1 0 15deg;}
}

@-o-keyframes object-skew {
0%   {rotate: 0 0 0 0deg;}
45%  {rotate: 1 1 0 15deg; }
50%  {rotate: 1 1 0 15deg;}
}

@keyframes object-skew {
0%   {rotate: 0 0 0 0deg;}
45%  {rotate: 1 1 0 15deg; }
50%  {rotate: 1 1 0 15deg;}
}
```

```html
<p>This doesn't work in any browser</p>
<div class="object-wraps"></div>
```

```css
 

.object-wraps {width: 100px; height: 100px; background: green;}

.object-wraps:hover {
    -webkit-animation-name: object-skew; 
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    
    -moz-animation-name: object-skew; 
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-duration: 2s;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    
    -o-animation-name: object-skew; 
    -o-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -o-animation-duration: 2s;
    -o-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    
    animation-name: object-skew; 
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes object-skew {
0%   {rotate: 0 0 0 0deg;}
45%  {rotate: 1 1 0 15deg; }
50%  {rotate: 1 1 0 15deg;}
}

@-moz-keyframes object-skew {
0%   {rotate: 0 0 0 0deg;}
45%  {rotate: 1 1 0 15deg; }
50%  {rotate: 1 1 0 15deg;}
}

@-o-keyframes object-skew {
0%   {rotate: 0 0 0 0deg;}
45%  {rotate: 1 1 0 15deg; }
50%  {rotate: 1 1 0 15deg;}
}

@keyframes object-skew {
0%   {rotate: 0 0 0 0deg;}
45%  {rotate: 1 1 0 15deg; }
50%  {rotate: 1 1 0 15deg;}
}
```

```html
 <p>This only works on Firefox</p>
<div class="object-wraps"></div>
```

I added the browser suppor until I realised that only firefox fully supports this. However, this code has stopped running on Firefox as well. Why is that?

This works:

```
.object-wraps:hover {
animation-name: object-skew; 
animation-timing-function: linear;
animation-duration: 2s;
animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

@keyframes object-skew {
 0%   {rotate: 0 0 0 0deg;}
 45%  {rotate: 1 1 0 15deg;}
 50%  {rotate: 1 1 0 15deg;}
}
```

This doesn't:

```
.object-wraps:hover {
    -webkit-animation-name: object-skew; 
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    
    -moz-animation-name: object-skew; 
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-duration: 2s;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    
    -o-animation-name: object-skew; 
    -o-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -o-animation-duration: 2s;
    -o-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    
    animation-name: object-skew; 
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes object-skew {
0%   {rotate: 0 0 0 0deg;}
45%  {rotate: 1 1 0 15deg; }
50%  {rotate: 1 1 0 15deg;}
}

@-moz-keyframes object-skew {
0%   {rotate: 0 0 0 0deg;}
45%  {rotate: 1 1 0 15deg; }
50%  {rotate: 1 1 0 15deg;}
}

@-o-keyframes object-skew {
0%   {rotate: 0 0 0 0deg;}
45%  {rotate: 1 1 0 15deg; }
50%  {rotate: 1 1 0 15deg;}
}

@keyframes object-skew {
0%   {rotate: 0 0 0 0deg;}
45%  {rotate: 1 1 0 15deg; }
50%  {rotate: 1 1 0 15deg;}
}
```

I'm not expecting it to play in chrome etc. But why doesn't it play on firefox anymore?

EDIT: Replacing all {rotate: 1 1 0 15deg;} for the better supported {transform: rotate3d(1, 1, 0, 15deg);} gets both versions to work.

Comment: Works for me with no problem on Firefox Windows 10. Perhaps you could make your code into a working snippet which shows the problem on your Firefox. What OS are you on?

Comment: I'm on windows 10. Replacing all 

{rotate: 1 1 0 15deg;} for the better supported 

{transform: rotate3d(1, 1, 0, 15deg);}

gets both versions to work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after creating snippets, which was suggested to me by A Haworth, it seems that both options work in Firefox and none in any other browser as expected. So I guess the problem must have been something else in my website's code. It's still strange that it'd work until I added the browser frefixes.

I'm adding a third option, which should work in all modern browsers.

```css
.object-wraps {width: 100px; height: 100px; background: purple;}

.object-wraps:hover {
    -webkit-animation-name: object-skew; 
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    
    -moz-animation-name: object-skew; 
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-duration: 2s;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    
    -o-animation-name: object-skew; 
    -o-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -o-animation-duration: 2s;
    -o-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    
    animation-name: object-skew; 
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes object-skew {
0%   {transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 15deg);}
45%  {transform: rotate3d(1, 1, 0, 15deg);}
50%  {transform: rotate3d(1, 1, 0, 15deg);}
}

@-moz-keyframes object-skew {
0%   {transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 15deg);}
45%  {transform: rotate3d(1, 1, 0, 15deg);}
50%  {transform: rotate3d(1, 1, 0, 15deg);}
}

@-o-keyframes object-skew {
0%   {transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 15deg);}
45%  {transform: rotate3d(1, 1, 0, 15deg);}
50%  {transform: rotate3d(1, 1, 0, 15deg);}
}

@keyframes object-skew {
0%   {transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 15deg);}
45%  {transform: rotate3d(1, 1, 0, 15deg);}
50%  {transform: rotate3d(1, 1, 0, 15deg);}
}
```

```html
<p>This should work everywhere</p>
<div class="object-wraps"></div>
```